# get all task. Only if user is the last comment on post using sql. is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

task table https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMVhS.png

task_assign table https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaFVB.png

task_comments table https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ns1n.png

here is my query but still return 2 records

```
select distinct t.task_id, ta.*,t.* from task_assign as ta 
inner join tasks t on t.task_id = ta.task_id 
where ta.user_id = 2 and ta.user_id is not null 
and t.task_id IN (
    # get task_id
    select distinct `task_comments`.`task_id` from `task_comments` 
    where `task_comments`.`task_id` is not null 
    and `task_comments`.`user_id`
    and `task_comments`.`task_id` = (
        #last comment
        select DISTINCT `task_comments`.`user_id` from `task_comments`
        where `task_comments`.`task_id` = ta.task_id
        order by `date_added` 
        desc limit 1
    )
)
```

my expected actual result must be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfeX6.png)

```
select distinct t.task_id, ta.*,t.* from task_assign as ta 
inner join tasks t on t.task_id = ta.task_id 
where ta.user_id = 2 and ta.user_id is not null 
and t.task_id IN (1) <- because current user_id 2 is the last on task 1
```

Comment: Can you explain what should be your output? `Example: It would contains only tasks with one comment.` This would help us to understand your problem and provide you a better way to handle it.

Comment: scenario: user_id 2 is login

i want to get all task base on task_assign table, only should return task that has last comment by user_id 2 base on are scenario.